# Advanced find format, copy, and paste

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document that has a bunch of projects. I've gone through and certain projects are in red font if they are high priority.

I want to make a macro so that Word finds all instances of red font, saves those project names, and then pastes them in a list at the top of my document.

When I tried to do the Macro Recorder, this is what I got.

```
Sub HotTopics()
'
' HotTopics Macro
'
'

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorRed

     With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Font.Color = wdColorRed
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
End Sub
```

When I try running the macro, it says there is an error with Selection.copy because there is nothing to copy

Answer (score 0):

You didn't click Find while recording the macro. Note second last line.

```
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchKashida = False
            .MatchDiacritics = False
            .MatchAlefHamza = False
            .MatchControl = False
            .MatchByte = False
            .CorrectHangulEndings = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchFuzzy = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Copy
```